# Angular strict mode : formGroup expects a FormGroup instance FormBuilder

Tags: angular, mode, formbuilder, strict

With Angular in strict mode, I have an error that I cannot resolve with FormBuilder.

The app checks for an ip with :

Code for `saisie.component.ts` :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-saisie',
  templateUrl: './saisie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./saisie.component.scss']
})

export class SaisieComponent implements OnInit {

  ipForm!: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ipForm = this.fb.group({
      ip: ["", Validators.required, Validators.pattern('(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)')]
    });
  }

  get f() { return this.ipForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    console.log("ip :" + this.ipForm.value.login);

    if (this.ipForm.invalid) {
      console.log("vide");
      return;
    }

    alert('JSon :\n ' + JSON.stringify(this.ipForm.value, null));
  }

  onReset() {
    this.isSubmitted = false;
    this.ipForm.reset();
  }
}
```

And for `saisie.component.html` :

```html
<form [formGroup]="identForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">IPv4 :</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" formControlName="ip" class="form-control"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.ip.errors }" placeholder="n.n.n.n" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.ip.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.ip.errors.required">Une IP valide est requise !</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field is-grouped">
        <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-link">Soumettre</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The `ipForm! = FormGroup` statement is required for strict mode but implies uninitialization.
I can of course put an `*ngIf` in the template but in this case the form does not appear.

I did various form initializations but none worked. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Why `ipForm` in component ts and `identForm` in html template ?

Comment: Exact ! an unforgivable mistake. I suspected it was such a mistake but I couldn't see it. Thank you.
I took the opportunity to also set two others: the validators between brackets and the output by this.ipForm.value.ip from the console ...
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the type in the template (as pointed out in the comments by @Rishanthakumar), you can initialize `FormGroup` in `strict` mode like this:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup()
```

And then reinitialize in `ngOnInit` or `constructor` as required with details.